# ASP .NET WebAPI - Signing PDF document with certificate occasionally fails with 'Keyset is not defined' exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, digital-signature, x509certificate2, hsm

On my project we're using a hosted HSM service to sign PDF documents that the application generates with a valid certificate. Basically, the setup consists of a certificate installed on the web server which is, through a client driver, connected to a private key on the remote HSM. We're using the iText library to generate PDFs and do the signing.

The C# implementation instructions were provided by the certificate authority which is also the hosted HSM provider. Our implementation differs from the example they provided very slightly in trivial details.
The problem is that signing PDFs occasionally stops working (with no changes to the code being made) with one of 2 cryptographic exceptions - either 'The keyset is not defined' or 'Bad data'. The exception seems to get thrown by the X509Certificate2 class constructor.

The problem seems to resolve itself after a period of time, from a few hours to about 2 days. This is causing major issues for us since generating signed PDFs is a core feature of the application.
We were able to verify that the Luna SA client side drivers are installed properly and that they can connect to a partition on the remote HSM. Also, all user permissions for accessing the local certificate (that is, the one on the web server) seem to be in order (i.e. the account the application pool running the app has full permissions on it).

Frankly, this has been driving us nuts since it seems to be happening at random with no changes to the code/hosting environment being made. The hosted HSM provider insists that 'they have not noticed anything strange on their end' and, on top of that, the whole thing seems to be poorly documented and I haven't been able to find any pointers not leading to dead ends online so far.
Any input would be **greatly** appreciated.

Comment: did you get anything further? I have also some issues with this. How do you know they can connect to the remote HSM? and how do you set the user permissions?